# Appending Dictionaries to a Python List: Strange Result?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I recently came across a strange observation while creating list of dictionaries by appending dictionaries to a list.

Below is my code:

```
a = []
    
for i in range(5):
    m = {'a':'apple'}
    a.append(m)
    m['b'] = 'ball'

for i in a:
    print(i)
```

I expected that the list `a` will only contain `'a': 'apple'` as the key `b` is defined after the append statement.

Suprisingly, below is the output I obtained:

```
{'a': 'apple', 'b': 'ball'}
{'a': 'apple', 'b': 'ball'}
{'a': 'apple', 'b': 'ball'}
{'a': 'apple', 'b': 'ball'}
{'a': 'apple', 'b': 'ball'}
```

Why does this happen? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The list contains a reference to the dictionary so when you change that same reference (in the body of the for loop) it'll change both the local version and the one in the list.

Comment: Not really strange if you know how references work

Comment: To clarify, there is no *local* or *list* version. There is only a single `dict` object, that is referenced by both the variable `m` (temporarily) and the list element. Any mutations to that object are reflected across all references.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because 2 things in python:

1. dict in python is a mutable object. In your code, the `m` is a dict, even it's been appended to object `a`. Its value can still be updated after that. This will affect the value been appended to `a` too.
2. function parameter is always assigned by Reference in python. In code `a.append(m)`, you are not passing m's value to `append()` but m's reference. So when you update m's value, a's value will be updated as well.

I suggest you can study the mutable and immutable objects in python further.